# Constants for both .cpp and .R files

Tags: c++, header, rcpp

I am building an R package and have a constant that I want to declare, `wjtConstant`. I want this constant to be accessible for both R functions AND .cpp functions that I create for the package

For R functions, I can create a .R file with one line: `wjtConstant = 5`
and place this file in the "R" folder for package development.

For the cpp functions, I can place the following line in a header file located within the "inst/include" folder: `const int wjtConstant = 5;`

I can declare the constants in both places and the results work as desired (i.e., the constants can be used by both R and cpp functions), but this feels sloppy. Is there any way to declare the constant once, and have it accessible for both R functions and cpp functions?

Comment: Can you place the values into a file and read the file?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Thomas. Please clarify, what type of "file" and where would I "read" the file?

Comment: The "type" of file can be anything, although I recommend text because it can be easily modified by a text editor.  You can read the file from anywhere.  I don't suggest placing the file in the ocean or on the Moon.  Most likely, it should be in a place that your executable has permission to access.

Answer (score 2):

You could use active bindings in R to call the C++ function. Something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

const int wjtConstant = 5;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int get_wjtConstant(){ return wjtConstant ; }
```

And in R:

```
> makeActiveBinding("wjtConstant", get_wjtConstant, environment() )
> wjtConstant
[1] 5
```

This way you can directly use `wjtConstant` both in R and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trivial example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

const int theAnswer = 42;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int getAnswer() {
  return theAnswer;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void callAnswer() {
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Accessing Answer in C++: " << theAnswer << std::endl;
} 

/*** R
cat("The answer is ", getAnswer(), "\n")
cat("Calling code accessing answer\n")
callAnswer()
*/
```

which produces:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/constEx.cpp")

R> cat("The answer is ", getAnswer(), "\n")
The answer is  42 

R> cat("Calling code accessing answer\n")
Calling code accessing answer

R> callAnswer()
Accessing Answer in C++: 42
R>
```

For a *real* solution, you'd have the constants in one which gets sourced
from an R accessor package as well as from a C++ consumer.  I had predictive systems use such a scheme to simplify / automate parameter updates.

Answer (score 0):

When mixing languages, placing constants or configuration data into files is an easy solution.  The file also allows the data to be changed without rebuilding the source files.

When using configuration or data files, the location for the file is in a folder that applications have read access to.

The file can be of any format, although a text format is useful for modifying with a text editor.  Binary formats are more difficult to modify.

Comment: Values in a file are more like _parameters_ whereas the question was about _constants_.

Comment: The values in a file can be treated as *constants* as well.  A file will allow you to change the constants without rebuilding.  Changes to constants in a header file will cause the sources to be retranslated.